# Aurelia: changing the name (attribute) of a bindable

Tags: aurelia

I want to know if it's possible to change the name (attribute name in HTML) of a bindable in Aurelia. Because of coding standards we're using in my current project, the attribute names we're using are very ugly, for example: `m-data="someData"`. We prefix all class members with `m`. I know I can use it for the class, so the custom element names are customizable, but can I also do this for bindables?

For example:

```
// my-component.js

// I can use a decorator here to
// change the custom element name, which is great!
@customElement('my-component')
export class clsMyComponent {
  @bindable mData;
}
```

Which results in the following:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<my-component m-data.bind="someData"></my-component>
```

So what I want to do, but doesn't work, is:

```
@customElement('my-component')
export class clsMyComponent {
  @bindable({name: 'data'}) mData;
}
```

I couldn't find anything on this, I know you can set stuff like two-way binding, default value, etc. But not the name right? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after some research I found out the correct answer to this question. As described in the [Aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/8) (search for 'bindable signature'). You can set the attribute name like this:

```
@customElement('my-component')
export class clsMyComponent {
  @bindable({attribute: 'data'}) mData;
}
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<my-component data.bind="someData"></my-component>
```

Comment: Bless you my child